# ADVANCE_QUICKSORT: print every step of partition/insertion

Tags: java, algorithm, quicksort, implementation, insertion-sort

I've learned and coded QuickSort(), Partition() and InsertionSort() myself, hence be able to run the code and sort arrays correctly, but what if I want to print in java and show every single steps the SORT algorithms do?

***Demand:

***Use QuickSort combines InsertionSort to enhence the efficiency.
If the amount of element of left/right subArray which devided by pivot is below 3(A[0..n-1], n<=3),

***=>use InsertionSort()

The output should be like this:

```
<BEFORE SORTING>:[10, 4, 2, 8, 7, 3, 5, 9, 6, 1]
use_partition:[1, 4, 2, 8, 7, 3, 5, 9, 6, 10]
use_partition:[1, 3, 2, 4, 7, 8, 5, 9, 6, 10]
use_insertion:[1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 8, 5, 9, 6, 10]
use_partition:[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 8, 10]
use_partition:[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
<AFTER SORTING>:[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

I would like to print the steps by java making the implementation more clearly, my first thought is to use some conditional loop, does anyone know where can I find the relative article? Thanks a lot.

---

Sorry, here's the code I wrote:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
public class Main{
   public static void main(String args[]){
      int[] array1 = {10, 4, 2, 8, 7, 3, 5, 9, 6, 1};
      int n1 = array1.length;
      System.out.print("Before sorting is: ");
      System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array1));
      System.out.print("After sorting is: ");
      Quicksort(array1, 0, n1-1);
      /*
      the display loop I need
      */
   } //end main()

    public static void Quicksort(int[] array, int start, int end){
        if(start<end){
            if(end-start <=3){
           InsertionSort(array, start, end);
        }else{
            int pivot = HoarePartition(array, start, end); 
            Quicksort(array, start, pivot); 
            Quicksort(array, pivot+1, end);}    
        }
        }
    } //end Quicksort()

    public static void swapIJ(int[] array, int i, int j){
        int temp = array[i];
        array[i] = array[j];
        array[j] = temp;
    } //end swapIJ

    public static int HoarePartition(int[] array, int start, int end){
        int pivot = array[start];
        int i = start -1 ;
        int j = end + 1;
        while(true){
            do{i++;}while(array[i] < pivot);
            do{j--;}while(array[j] > pivot);

            if(i>=j)
               return j;
            swapIJ(array, i, j);
        } //end while
    } //end HoarePartition()

    public static void InsertionSort(int[] array) {
       for(int i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
           int temp = array[i];
           int j = i - 1;
        
           while(j >= 0 && array[j] > temp) {
               array[j + 1] = array[j];
               j--;
           }
           array[j + 1] = temp;
       } //end for
    } //end InsertionSort()
```

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in the comments, you could place a `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array))` at every call of your `quicksort` method. This will print the state of your array at every sorting iteration.

For example, in your code it could be placed in the `HoarePartition` method right before returning.

```
public static int HoarePartition(int[] array, int start, int end) {
    int pivot = array[start];
    int i = start - 1;
    int j = end + 1;
    while (true) {
        do {
            i++;
        } while (array[i] < pivot);
        do {
            j--;
        } while (array[j] > pivot);

        if (i >= j) {
            //Printing the array status after the updates and right before returning
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
            return j;
        }
        swapIJ(array, i, j);
    } //end while
} //end HoarePartition()
```

Comment: Thanks! I think now I got some idea for where to place the toString() methods, I'm trying it now.